# How to find out whether the user crossed the next turn or not using corelocation in iOS?

Tags: google-maps, ios7, core-location

I have drawn path on GMSMapview based on latitude and longitudes returned by Google maps API, and I am allowing user to start navigation using this path. 
Here my doubt is how can I know that that whether the user is crossed the next turn and how can I ensure that the user is following the same path(drawn by me)?

For ex, If I get 4 turns[(lat1,long1), (lat2, long2), (lat3,long3), (lat4,long4) from google apis, the moment user crossed the 1st turn (lat1,long1) I need to display a toast, suppose if the taken straight root(wrong root) instead of crossing the turn I need to display warning toast.

I am just guessing like may be by tracking user's heading direction we can achieve this, correct me If I am wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: I think the `func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading!)` method from `CLLocationManagerDelegate` will help you achieve this.

Comment: But this method is getting called whenever device heading is updated. My requirement is.. I need to know only when the users heading is updated, not device heading.

Answer (score 0):

You path is array of coordinates, right? Use - distanceFromLocation: method to see if your user's location is close enough to any of coordinates in your array. Once user is, say, more than 100 meters from any and all coordinates in your array - you know user is off the path.

Then if you can figure out which exact coordinates are "turns", you can track user getting closer to the turn and once user starts getting farther from the turn point while still staying on your path - he's made the turn.